# Notación infija a postfija en JAVA

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos, pilas

Espero que estén muy bien.

Quisiera que me ayudaran por favor con el siguiente código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class InfijaPrePost {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
//se lee la notacion
    System.out.println("introduce notacion");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String notacion=sc.nextLine();
    
    //se llama al metodo postFija introduciendo como parametro la cadena ingresada por el usuario
    System.out.println(postFija(notacion));

}

/**
 * Metodo que retorna el array, compara cada elemento
 * segun la jerarquia de un operador en la notacion infija
 * recibida por el usuario.
 * 
 * @param infija Recibe la cadena dada por el usuario
 * @return la expresion de infija a postFija
 */
public static char[] postFija(String infija)
{
    /**
     * variable organizada de mayor a menor jerarquia
     */
    String jerarquia="^*/+- ";
    
    /**
     * variable para recorrer la posicion de la cadena infija
     */
    int pos_infija=0;
    /**
     * variable para recorrer la posicion de la variable jerarquia
     */
    int pos_jer=0;
    
    /**
     * creacion de un array para introducir los elementos de infija
     */
    char array[]=new char[infija.length()];
    
    /**
     * se introduce cada elemento de infija al array
     */
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {
        array[i]=infija.charAt(i);
    }
    
    /**
     * mientras la posicion de jerarquia no llegue a la posicion final de la variable jerarquia
     */
    while(pos_jer!=jerarquia.length()-1)
    {
        /**
         * Prueba de pantalla
         */
        /*for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(array[i]+" ");
        }*/
        //System.out.println("");
        
        /**
         * se valida si la posición de la variable infija esta en el elemento final de dicha variable (infija)
         * en caso de ser verdadero, reestablecera la posición y aumentara en 1 la posición de la variable jerarquía
         */
        if(pos_infija==infija.length() )
        {
            pos_infija=0;
            pos_jer++;
        }
        
        /**
         * se compara el elemento de la notacion infija y la variable jerarquia
         * 
         */
        if(infija.charAt(pos_infija) == jerarquia.charAt(pos_jer) )
        {
            char aux = ' ';
            
            /**
             * se hace un "swap"
             */
            aux=array[pos_infija];
            
            array[pos_infija]=array[pos_infija+1];
            array[pos_infija+1]=aux;
            
            /*for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
            {
                System.out.print(array[i]+" ");
            }*/
        }
        /**
         * se incrementa en 1 la posición de la notación infija para volverla a comparar
         */
        pos_infija++;
    }
    
    
    return array;
}

}
```

Lo que sucede es que quiero convertir una expresión ingresada por teclado y de esta manera la convierta a **notación postfija**. Mi problema es que cuando ingreso por ejemplo `x+z*w` el programa imprime: `xy+w**` en donde su notación postfija correcta seria: `xzw*+`

Los paréntesis `()` no sabría **"priorizarlos"** para que el programa también lea notaciones con paréntesis.

Muchas gracias de antemano, espero que por favor me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Yo tengo este código en neatbens donde convierto la notación infija a postfija, y se puede hacer con paréntesis solo que tengo un problema donde al ingresa por

```
ejemplo:
(A+B)*(C+D)
Me regresa:
AB+*CD+
Cuando deberia ser:
AB+CD+*
```

No se si sea problema de mi maquina, pero inténtalo y si te falla y logras corregir el error me dices

Clase Principal:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String Expresion, postfija="";  
        int i=0;
        Tipo_Pila Pila = new Tipo_Pila();
        Expresion = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Teclear la expresión a validar:"); 
        char simbolo,elemento;
        while(i<Expresion.length()){
            simbolo=Expresion.charAt(i);
            if(!Pila.esOperador(simbolo))
                postfija+=simbolo;
            else{
                while(!Pila.pilaVacia() &&
                        Pila.Precedencia(Pila.Cima(), simbolo) ){
                    elemento=Pila.quitar();
                    postfija += elemento;
                }
                if (simbolo != ')') 
                    Pila.insertar(simbolo);  
                else           
                    Pila.quitar();
            }
            i++;
        }
        while(!Pila.pilaVacia()){
            elemento = Pila.quitar();
            postfija += elemento;
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, postfija);
    }
```

Clase Secundaria:

```
package postfija_parentesis;
public class Tipo_Pila {
    final static int MAX_ELEMENTOS = 100; 
    private int error;
    private int cima; 
    private char elemento[];
    public Tipo_Pila() {
        error = 0;
        cima = -1;
        elemento = new char [MAX_ELEMENTOS];  
    }
    public void insertar(char d) {  
        if (!pilaLlena()) elemento[++cima]= d; 
        else   
            error = 1;   
    } 
    public char quitar() { 
        if (!pilaVacia()) return elemento[cima--]; 
        else {
            error = 2; 
            return ' '; 
        }     
    }         
    public boolean pilaVacia() { 
        if (cima == -1)return true; 
        else 
            return false;   
    } 
    public boolean pilaLlena() { 
        if (cima == (MAX_ELEMENTOS - 1))return true; 
        else 
            return false;
    }     
    public int muestraError() {
        return error;
    } 
    public boolean Basico(char op){
        boolean r=false;
        if(op=='+') r=true;
        if(op=='-') r=true;
        if(op=='*') r=true;
        if(op=='/') r=true;
        if(op=='^') r=true;
        return r;
    }
    public boolean esOperador(char op){
        boolean r =Basico(op);
        switch (op){
            case '(':
            case ')': r=true;break;
        }
        return r;
    }
    public boolean Precedencia(char op, char op2){
        boolean r=false;
        if(op=='^' && Basico(op2)) r=true;
        if(op=='*' || op=='/' && Basico(op2) && op2!='^') r=true;
        if(op=='+' || op=='-' && op2=='+' || op2=='-') r=true;
        if(Basico(op) && op2==')')r=true;
        return r;
    }
    public char Cima(){
        return elemento [cima];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto es mas viejo que cagar al campo. Hay mucha documentacion, ejemplos y algoritmos ahí fuera:

```
// Funcion que convierte una expresion matematica en notacion infija a notacion postfija
    public static String convertirInfijaPostfija(String infija) {
        StringBuilder postfija = new StringBuilder();  // StringBuilder para construir la cadena de salida
        Stack<Character> pila = new Stack<>();  // Pila para almacenar los operadores
        
        // Recorre cada caracter de la expresion infija
        for (int i = 0; i < infija.length(); i++) {
            char c = infija.charAt(i);
            
            // Si el caracter es un operando, se anade a la salida
            if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)) {
                postfija.append(c);
            }
            
            // Si el caracter es un parentesis de apertura, se anade a la pila
            else if (c == '(') {
                pila.push(c);
            }
            
            // Si el caracter es un parentesis de cierre, se sacan los operadores de la pila y se anaden a la salida
            // hasta encontrar el parentesis de apertura correspondiente
            else if (c == ')') {
                while (!pila.isEmpty() && pila.peek() != '(') {
                    postfija.append(pila.pop());
                }
                if (!pila.isEmpty() && pila.peek() == '(') {
                    pila.pop();  // saca el parentesis de apertura de la pila
                }
            }
            
            // Si el caracter es un operador, se sacan los operadores de la pila y se anaden a la salida
            // mientras tengan mayor o igual precedencia que el operador actual
            else {
                while (!pila.isEmpty() && precedencia(pila.peek()) >= precedencia(c)) {
                    postfija.append(pila.pop());
                }
                pila.push(c);  // anade el operador actual a la pila
            }
        }
        
        // Saca los operadores restantes de la pila y los anade a la salida
        while (!pila.isEmpty()) {
            postfija.append(pila.pop());
        }
        
        return postfija.toString();  // devuelve la cadena en notacion postfija
    }
    
    // Funcion que devuelve la precedencia de un operador
    public static int precedencia(char operador) {
        switch (operador) {
            case '+':
            case '-':
                return 1;
            case '*':
            case '/':
                return 2;
            case '^':
                return 3;
            default:
                return -1;
        }
    }
    
    // Ejemplo de uso
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String infija = "(A+B)*C";
        String postfija = convertirInfijaPostfija(infija);
        System.out.println(postfija);  // Salida esperada: "abc*+def^/g*-"
    }
```